# Pandas: Transform pairs of columns to cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
ts | thing_0 | qty_0 | thing_1 | qty_1 | thing_2 | qty_2
--------------------------------------------------------
1  | dog     |     5 | cat     |     3 | mouse   |     1
2  | house   |     6 | dog     |     4 | cat     |     2
...
```

I want to transform this in a way that the `thing`s become columns and the `qty`s become the cell values. Like this:

```
ts | dog | cat | mouse | house
------------------------------
1  |   5 |   3 |     1 |     0
2  |   4 |   2 |     0 |     6
...
```

Currently, I'm doing this transformation manually by iterating over the `df.values` array manually, but this is very slow. Is there a faster way to implement this with pandas means?

I have seen [df.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), but couldn't find a way to describe the relationship between `thing_0` and `qty_0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` from columns by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index('ts')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .set_index('thing', append=True)['qty'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
thing  cat  dog  house  mouse
ts                           
1        3    5      0      1
2        2    4      6      0
```

Another solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) instead `unstack`:

```
df = df.set_index('ts')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack().reset_index()
df = df.pivot(index='ts', columns='thing', values='qty').fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
thing  cat  dog  house  mouse
ts                           
1        3    5      0      1
2        2    4      6      0
```

And third solution - dynamically create dict for [`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857) and then use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

*Notice - columns have to be sorted, if not add `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)`*

```
t = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('thing')]
q = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('qty')]
df = pd.lreshape(df, {'thing':t, 'qty':q})
       .set_index(['ts','thing'])['qty'].unstack(fill_value=0)

print (df)
thing  cat  dog  house  mouse
ts                           
1        3    5      0      1
2        2    4      6      0
```

EDIT:

[`lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L857) is now undocumented, but is possible in future will by removed ([with pd.wide_to_long too](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15003#issuecomment-324625271)).

Possible solution is merging all 3 functions to one - maybe `melt`, but now it is not implementated. Maybe in some new version of pandas. Then my answer will be updated.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `lreshape` to coalesce the `thing` and `qty` columns:

```
In [10]: pd.lreshape(df, {'thing':['thing_0','thing_1','thing_2',], 'qty':['qty_0','qty_1','qty_2']})
Out[10]: 
   ts  thing  qty
0   1    dog    5
1   2  house    6
2   1    cat    3
3   2    dog    4
4   1  mouse    1
5   2    cat    2
```

Then `pivot` to create the desired DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'qty_0': [5, 6], 'qty_1': [3, 4], 'qty_2': [1, 2], 'thing_0': ['dog', 'house'], 'thing_1': ['cat', 'dog'], 'thing_2': ['mouse', 'cat'], 'ts': [1, 2]})

reshaped = pd.lreshape(df, {'thing':['thing_0','thing_1','thing_2',], 
                            'qty':['qty_0','qty_1','qty_2']})

result = reshaped.pivot(index='ts', columns='thing', values='qty')
print(result)
```

yields

```
thing  cat  dog  house  mouse
ts                           
1      3.0  5.0    0.0    1.0
2      2.0  4.0    6.0    0.0
```

---

I think [jezrael's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44969883/190597) is better since it takes advantage of the regularity of the column names you wish to coalesce. `df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)` is more general and less repetitive than

```
{'thing':['thing_0','thing_1','thing_2',], 
 'qty':['qty_0','qty_1','qty_2']}
```

`lreshape` might be helpful in situations where the column names you wish to coalesce
are irregular.